# Simulate a Java generic interface and abstract data type in C

Tags: c, interface, function-pointers

I am trying to port a library written in Java into C programming language. For Java interface, I intend to use a struct of function-pointers to replace, for instance:

```java
// Java code
public interface ActionsFunction {  
    Set<Action> actions(Object s);
}

/* C code */
typedef struct ActionsFunction {    
    List* (*actions)(void* s);    
    void (*clear_actions)(struct List **list); /* Since C doesn't have garbage collector */
} ActionsFunction;
```

My question is: whether it is a suitable solution or not, and how can I simulate a generic interface such as:

```java
public interface List <E> {
    void add(E x);
    Iterator<E> iterator();
}
```

**UPDATE**:

I also have to face with another problem: implementing generic abstract data structure like List, Queue, Stack, etc since the C standard library lacks of those implementation. My approach is client code should pass the pointer of its data accompanying with its size, thus allowing library to hold that one without specifying its type. One more time, it just my idea. I need your advices for the design as well as implementing technique.

My initial porting code can be found at:
https://github.com/PhamPhiLong/AIMA

generic abstract data structure can be found in **utility** sub folder.

Comment: Hmmm, playing with macros, maybe?

Comment: If you want full OO power, you'll need to do a little more but maybe it is not required for your application.  Did you have a look at OO frameworks for C like [GObject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GObject)?  Generics in Java are actually just statically checked typecasts so you might just use the base pointer.  Finally, your English sounds fine to me.  No need to apologize.

Comment: If you want to simulate Java generics in C, just remember that Java generics aren't all that generic; they are just syntactic sugar for inserting all the casts at the call-site.

Comment: @5gon12eder: Since when are those type-casts statically checked?

Comment: @Deduplicator Since day number 1, no?

Comment: @5gon12eder: Rather, never were. It's just not possible without a complete analysis of the data-flow, which would be far too heavy-weight for the JIT. Even C++ compilers, which have lots more time and resources to "get things right", mostly give up on it, aside from simple cases.

Comment: Don't worry about the generics.  Everything inside `<>` is just ignored at run-time.  So just drop them when you produce the C, and if there's a variable whose type is a generic, just use `void *`.

Comment: @Deduplicator I wasn't talking about the JIT compiler but the “Java compiler” that's (usually) producing the byte code.  I guess you can trick the system out by replacing byte code files after compilation but the Java code *is* checked.

Comment: What about java2c? http://sourceforge.net/projects/java2c/   would that not be worth a try?

Comment: How to use the `ActionsFunction` as a interface? Can you show some example?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a very brief example using macros to accomplish something like this. This can get hairy pretty quick, but if done correctly, you can maintain complete static type safety.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define list_type(type)     struct __list_##type

/* A generic list node that keeps 'type' by value. */
#define define_list_val(type)           \
    list_type(type) {                   \
        list_type(type) *next;          \
        type value;                     \
    }

#define list_add(plist, node)                       \
do                                                  \
{                                                   \
    typeof(plist) p;                                \
    for (p = plist; *p != NULL; p = &(*p)->next) ;  \
    *p = node;                                      \
    node->next = NULL;                              \
} while(0)

#define list_foreach(plist, p)                      \
for (p = *plist; p != NULL; p = p->next)


define_list_val(int)    *g_list_ints;
define_list_val(float)  *g_list_floats;


int main(void)
{
    list_type(int) *node;

    node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    node->value = 42; 
    list_add(&g_list_ints, node);

    node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    node->value = 66; 
    list_add(&g_list_ints, node);


    list_foreach(&g_list_ints, node) {
        printf("Node: %d\n", node->value);
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for "you can maintain complete static type safety".  This is a great reason to use this approach over anything I suggested.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few common ways to do generic-ish programming in C.  I would expect to use one or more of the following methods in trying to accomplish the task you've described.

**MACROS:** One is to use macros.  In this example, MAX looks like a function, but operate on anything that can be compared with the ">" operator:

```
#define MAX(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))

int   i;
float f;
unsigned char b;
f = MAX(7.4, 2.5)
i = MAX(3, 4)
b = MAX(10, 20)
```

**VOID ***: Another method is to use `void *` pointers for representing generic data, and then pass function pointers into your algorithms to operate on the data.  Look up the `<stdlib.h>` function `qsort` for a classic example of this technique.

**UNIONS**: Yet another, though probably seen less often, technique is to use unions to hold data of multiple different types.  This makes your algorithms that operate on the data kinda ugly though and might not save much coding:

```
enum { VAR_DOUBLE, VAR_INT, VAR_STRING }

/* Declare a generic container struct for any type of data you want to operate on */
struct VarType
{
    int     type;
    union   data 
    {
       double d;
       int    i;
       char * sptr;
    };
} 

int main(){
  VarType x;
  x.data.d = 1.75;
  x.type   = VAR_DOUBLE;
  /* call some function that sorts out what to do based on value of x.type */
  my_function( x );  
}
```

**CLEVER CASTING & POINTER MATH** It's a pretty common idiom to see data structures with functions that operate on a specific kind of struct and then require that the struct by included in your struct to do anything useful.

The easy way to do this, is the force the struct that allows insertion into the data structure to be the first member of your derived type.  Then you can seamless cast back & forth between the two.   The more versatile way is to use 'offsetof'.  Here's a simple example.

For example:

```
/* Simple types */
struct listNode { struct listNode * next; struct listNode * prev };
struct list { struct listNode dummy; }

 /* Functions that operate on those types */
int append( struct list * theList, struct listNode * theNode );
listNode * first( struct list *theList );

/* To use, you must do something like this: */

/* Define your own type that includes a list node */
typedef struct {
   int x; 
   double y; 
   char name[16]; 
   struct listNode node;
} MyCoolType;

int main() {
   struct list   myList;
   MyCoolType    coolObject;
   MyCoolType  * ptr;

   /* Add the 'coolObject's 'listNode' member to the list */
   appendList( &myList, &coolObject.node );

   /* Use ugly casting & pointer math to get back you your original type 
      You may want to google 'offsetof' here. */
   ptr = (MyCoolType *) ( (char*) first( &myList )
           - offsetof(MyCoolType,node);
}
```

The libev documentation has some more good examples of this last technique:

http://search.cpan.org/dist/EV/libev/ev.pod#COMMON_OR_USEFUL_IDIOMS_(OR_BOTH)

Comment: your answer is very helpful. Although my intention for this question is focusing on porting Java interface which basically defines prototype of those functions that the client code will call from its library, you just reminded me another problem that I have to face with when implement basic abstract data structure since C standard library doesn't include list, queue, etc implementation likes Java. My approach is creating interface for each ADS (simply a struct of function pointers). The library doesn't need to care about the type of it node but the pointer accompanying with its size.